# Matplotlib savefig not working - Dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe and want to perform a bar graph with it.

My dataframe looks like:
Aerogenerator Yaw_CCW  Yaw_CW
T01            100      99
T02            150      155
...

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 12
y = 6
z = 1200

df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.figure(figsize=(x,y))
plt.title('Over 2000 yaws')
plt.ylabel('Yaw')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('crit.png', dpi = z, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
plt.close("all")
```

I do get my graph on anaconda as I wished:

[image: This is what I get on anaconda panel. I want to save this!]

However, when I open the image file I saved with savefig() I get this:
[image: This is what I am saving]

Comment: Did you figure this out? I ran into a similar issue.